# Invalid Registration error in GCM

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am getting following error I am trying to integrate Google Cloud Messaging in PHP to Android, Any solution

```
{"multicast_id":5864514048533725299,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration" }]}
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["regId"]) && isset($_GET["receiver_id"]) && isset($_GET["sender_id"])) {
    $regId = $_GET["regId"];
    $receiver_id = $_GET["receiver_id"];
    $sender_id = $_GET["sender_id"];
    include_once './db_functions.php';
    include_once './GCM.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();
    $gcm = new GCM();
//echo $sender_id. $receiver_id; exit;
    $res = $db->storeUser($sender_id, $receiver_id);
    $registatoin_ids = array($regId);
    $message = array("message" => 'You have friend request');
    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $sender_id, $receiver_id, $message);
    echo $result;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your device id is updated?
2. check whether API_key you have entered in web api is available at console.google.com?
3. check whether API_key belongs to the same project number you have used to generate device token?

> **Invalid Registration ID** Check the formatting of the registration ID
>   that you pass to the server. Make sure it matches the registration ID
>   the phone receives in the com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
>   intent and that you're not truncating it or adding additional
>   characters. Happens when error code is InvalidRegistration. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20642184/3134215)

So basically you are making an error in sending the DeviceID received by the phone to the server.

Comment: I am implementing in php. And API Key is also available. and checking in localhost.