# Unable to use Clevertap. Stuck at Push Test Notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, clevertap

I'm getting the error:

`Android: Error: Invalid Registration`

What could be the possible reason for this? I've followed all the steps given by CleverTap for integration but not sure why the error is still there...

*Using GCM.*

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [error code response](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes), if you receive the error `InvalidRegistration` try to check the format of the registration token you pass to the server. Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with GCM. Do not truncate or add additional characters.

For more information, you can also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641393/gcm-error-codes).

Answer (score 1):

The error "Invalid Registration" typically pops up if either the GCM Sender ID that has been used in the project is incorrect, or if the Server API key you have added to your CleverTap dashboard (i.e., in your Android Push Notification settings) is incorrect.

To solve this, please re-confirm if the GCM Sender ID in your application matches its Project Number from your GCM Console, then please generate a new Server API key, whitelist the required IP addresses (mentioned on the Android Push Notification settings page on the CleverTap dashboard), then go to your Android Push Notification settings on the CleverTap dashboard to re-add the key.