# TOPICS_MESSAGE_RATE_EXCEEDED when sending more than one message in a short period of time

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to send more than one message to a single topic in just one second.

I have three Android devices and I'm trying to send multiple downstream messages to a topic (the three devices are subscribed to) in a short period of time (one second). Our server does ACK for the three of them.

In that moment, we send two messages to the topic, but one of them returns NACK with an error message of `TOPICS_MESSAGE_RATE_EXCEEDED`.

And now, we retry to resend the message again, if `time_to_live` doesn't expire first. In our case, that message tried re-sending again when the user clicks on it again. Is this the correct behavior?

Did anyone have this problem before? How is it solved?

Comment: I'd assume by paying money.

Comment: If is that correct, where can I find a description of this problem?

Comment: I'd assume in the documentation where they say "if you want to use this service for real workloads, you need to pay money". I'm just assuming. It sounds like you're using a free version of something and it only allows you such pitiful transfer rates.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I'll check that.

Comment: FCM service is free. Regardless of which plan you are using.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the service level agreement of an external service

Comment: I think this is a valid question. If anything, it can be considered as low quality since minimal details were provided. However, the details itself (just the scenario) was sufficient, enough to provide an idea to what's happening.

Comment: I am new here and I learn how to write here. 

This is my scenario: Three android devices send message on one topic at same time(same second). Our server do ACK for three of them and try to do downstream to topic. In that moment we send two message to topic and one of them return NACK with error message TOPICS_MESSAGE_RATE_EXCEEDED. And now that message try to resend again if time to live no expires first. In our case that message try resend again like android user click on again. Is it correct behavior?  Can you tell as little closer to the procedure in our case?

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior for GCM/FCM. Sending multiple messages to a topic in a short amount of time will cause this error.

I think this serves as a *safety net* for GCM/FCM against *flooding* and is also about handling the traffic. Just imagine **if** you have a 1000 subscribers then you send multiple multiple messages in less than a second to that topic.

You should implement a delay (about 5-10 seconds) for each message you send to the topic.

Also mentioned by @Eran's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20642184/4625829) (which is based from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes)):

> **Topics Message Rate Exceeded** The rate of messages to subscribers to a particular topic is too high. Reduce the number of messages sent for this topic, and do not immediately retry sending.

Comment: Thank you for your time. This is good.  I have read about exponential backoff. Is that good idea?

Comment: @12345 Exponential backoff is normally used as a *fail safe*. You can use it if you like. But for your scenario, since the TOPICS_MESSAGE_RATE_EXCEEDED is already expected, you should simply implement delays when sending the messages to avoid it totally

Comment: @12345 Just wanted to check in on you. Are you still encountering the error even after implementing delays to your requests? I've noticed that you edited your post where you're trying to verify a behavior. I'm having difficulty in understanding it. Can you expound more?

Comment: We are receiving this error randomly. Even after not sending notifications for about 5 minutes we get it. For the same topic a minut later it suddently works, but then it might fail again later on. There must be something wrong in the backend of firebase, because the messaging/message-rate-exceeded and quota-rate-exceeded errors are randomly popping up